# How to use しっくり

Tags: words

> しかし着いて早早、私はお箸売り場でうずくまってしまうのだった。全然**しっくり**来ない。
>   = I arrived too early at the place selling chopsticks, and ended up squatting outside. Completely .... not come?

I went there at the wrong time? I didn't go appropriately? What's the meaning of the second sentence here?

Comment: Do you have more context (especially what comes before)?

Comment: 文脈がないと何のことだかわかんないですね・・

Answer (score 2, accepted):

しっくり by itself is an adverb meaning something like "nicely", "perfectly", describing how something fits well with something. But it's almost always used in combination with 来る, anyway.

～(と)来る after certain adverbs is something like "comes off to me as ～", "strikes me as ～", "It occurs to me that ～", etc. It's the fifth definition of デジタル大辞泉:

> ５ 何かによって、ある反応・感覚・感情が起こる。「ぴんとくる」「胸にじんとくる温かい言葉」

So しっくりと来ない literally means "it does not strike me as perfect" or something similar. It's a set phrase, and possible translations would be "I feel something is wrong", "I somehow feel uneasy", "It's kinda out of place", "It seems a bit off", etc. As mentioned in the comment, the cause of such a feeling is not mentioned in your excerpt.

～て早々【そうそう】 means "No later than ～", "As soon as ～".

Answer (score 2):

"しっくり来る" and "しっくり来ない" are both set phrases having quite opposite meanings.

**しっくり** is an adverb that has a nuance particular to Japan, and it has a meaning that the feeling is exactly fitting to the state which was expected in advance.
So **しっくり来る** literally means *it comes nicely* so it means *I'm comfortable* or *I feel comfortable*. We usually don't use kanji for しっくりくる and しっくりこない.

"**全然しっくり来ない**" in the context is something like "何て言ったらいいかわからないが、こんなんじゃない。不愉快だ。　*I don't know what to say, but this is totally different from what I have expected. So I feel uncomfortable*."

Comment: Could someone explain why this need to be downvoted? I feel downvoting is not something easily done without reason. The function says "This answer is not useful". Isn't this quite a strong objection?

Comment: this answer makes perfect sense. I would think the translation for 全然しっくり来ない in this context would have a meaning such as "I feel out of place" given the context

Answer (score 1):

> しかし着いて早早、私はお箸売り場でうずくまってしまうのだった。全然しっくり来ない。
>   = I arrived too early at the place selling chopsticks, and ended up squatting outside. Completely .... not come?
>
> I went there at the wrong time? I didn't go appropriately? What's the
>   meaning of the second sentence here?

From this alone, I can't tell everything, but it says as soon as (～して早々) arriving, the speaker would crouch down at the place.

This 全然しっくり来ない here doesn't really make clear sense to me either, but this 来ない never means an actual action of anyone. It's saying that it['dummy' it] doesn't come well at all. Maybe trying to say s/he doesn't feel well.

Comment: Could someone explain why this need to be downvoted? I feel downvoting is not something easily done without reason. The function says "This answer is not useful". Isn't this quite a strong objection?